# Prefix - something wrong in configuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, prefix

I created a new project 2 hours ago. Configured it the same way as my old (different) project, where everything is working.

In my `podfile` I have:

```
pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '2.0.0-rc2'
```

If I import in `AppDelegate`:

```
#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>
```

everything is working fine. No errors. I can write code (`DDLogs` etc) and it's working.

But if I import in `MyApp-Prefix.pch`:

```
#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>
```

I receive an error `'CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h' file not found`.

I've filled in `MyTarget -> Build Settings -> Prefix Header` correct path to the header. Besides, if I enter any macro in the prefix, I can use it later in any class without importing... So it seems to be working.

Any idea what can cause such issues?

*BTW: I want to use prefix. Please don't write comments 'don't use prefix', I am fully aware of both benefits and disadvantages.*

-- edit --

Also I'm not sure, but in my old project `libPods.a` was black, here it is red (meaning it's missing). Maybe they're build later and that's why I can't import it 'globally'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to fix the issue:

1. cmd+copy `.pch` contents.
2. Delete `.pch` file
3. Search through the project, remove everything where the name appears (probably only xcproj/xcworkspace)
4. add new `.pch` file
5. cmd+paste old contents to the new file
6. open workspace/project, open target, build settings, search for `Prefix Header`, write relative path to the file.

Everything is working now. But I still have no idea why it was working bad before. I've tried to reset Xcode, delete derived data, clean, remove pods and reinstall them - none worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, but the cause was Apple's mind-blowing incompetence: this is a bug that keeps regressing in Xcode versions, every single year, and they STILL forget to test it before shipping.

The "Framework search folders" (in fact: all the header search settings) in Xcode often is incompatible with the space character.

i.e. if there are any spaces in the folder path, your project will be corrupted (by Xcode!) when it saves the settings file.

You have to manually edit the path, delete all the fake / corrupt entries, and put in the correct entry, but surround it with double-quotes.

(NB: some versions of Xcode would detect this problem, and insert an EXTRA pair of quotes when loading the project. This gives you four quotes, which of course again breaks Xcode.)

Still broken in latest Xcode, 2016, version 7.x. Joy!

Comment: That is the correct answer. Thank you Adam, you saved me a lot of trouble.

Comment: @TimoJosten Please do note, that this answer was posted a year later than the question and the original answer. Also, my answer fixed my problem, and I'm the creator of both the question and the answer. While this answer is very good, you can't claim the other one is incorrect.

Comment: @Vive this is a problem that SO's fundamental design fails to deal with at all, and I think few people predicted ... and as far as I know, nothing is being done about. I've had some old solved answers get downvoted because the situation has changed during the lifetime of SO.com, so that they're no longer correct! :)

Comment: @Adam Well in fact I think the other answer does still work and does what required (if it's not please let me know). I'm not sure which one involves more work into it. It also solved the issue, I'd accept this answer otherwise. However you're right that there's a problem with the updates within a question... and recently I have troubles with quality as well - both of the questions and the answers. Anyway, that's the opinion and you, me or anyone else can have it's own - your right to tell something is invalid, but I'd like to know what, to improve myself & the answer. Have a nice day!

Comment: Your answer did not work for me, does not work for other people. There are multiple reasons a PCH file can fail - in my experience, the Apple bug of failing to handle spaces correctly is more common since about Xcode 4 (previous to that, corrupted PCHs were more common). It's fine that there is more than one correct answer, given the symptoms are shared across multiple problems.

Comment: In the first instance I deleted Xcode Derived Data and let the workspace be re-indexed and then built without any issues.